# Dynamically adjust text size in buttons inside Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-responsive-layout

I am using localization to support multiple languages in my app. This results in having text in buttons with different length. So I need to have it being responsive.

I have two buttons in a `Row()`. I want to adjust the textsize inside these buttons so they never produce any overflow. Currently it looks like this in some languages:

[image]

I tried using [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) with no success.

This is my code for the dialog:

```
return Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  width: kIsWeb ? 40.w : 100.w,
                  color: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.sp),
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        OutlinedButton(
                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                              side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              primary: Colors.black54),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.joinGameDialogCancelButton,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: kIsWeb ? 4.sp : 12.sp)),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              primary: Colors.white),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              widget.onFinished(nameController.text.trim());
                            }
                          },
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.joinGameDialogJoinButton,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: kIsWeb ? 4.sp : 14.sp),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                            stepGranularity: 1,
                            maxLines: 1,
                          )
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.sp)),
                    Text("some eula text"),
                  ]))
            ],
          ),
        )));
```

Comment: I suppose having the buttons on the same row is a must

Comment: @il_boga they are

Comment: I fear that if also `maxLines` on `AutoSizeText` must be 1 there's no way to achieve that. I did some trials, and only by increasing the lines I got something like what you need.

Comment: @il_boga a solution with maxlines > 1 would be at least something

Comment: I don't think having large texts with small fonts inside buttons or having multi-line texts there is a good idea. That's ugly, poor UX and accessibility. After all you won't find popular and nice UIs with that kind of tricks.. IMO the way to go is having short texts and same height/font buttons across the UI

Comment: @MaximSaplin yeah, you're probably right :|

Comment: @progNewbie what is expected UI when text won't be fit on single line

Answer (score 6):

You can use [FittedBox Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html)

```
 FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Text(
        "Your Text Here",
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextPainter combined without layoutBuilder to determine if the text has overflowed or not, then dynamically resize the text to fit.

Wrapping in a layoutBuilder will determine how much space is available. The textPainter will simulate the rendering of the text and tell you if it has overflowed.

You can save your text size in a variable within the widget state, then decrement the textSize and call setState until the text fits.

See this similar question: [How to check if Flutter Text widget was overflowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114778/how-to-check-if-flutter-text-widget-was-overflowed)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I used: I do not have a mobile device to test it, so I used Windows (but I guess this should not be a problem). In this way, the text gets cut off instead of getting an overflow when it can't get smaller:

```
         return Dialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        //width: 100,
                        color: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              OutlinedButton(
                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                    side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                    primary: Colors.black54),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const Text("weerwerewrweee", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        primary: Colors.white),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      // if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                      //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      //   widget.onFinished(nameController.text.trim());
                                      // }
                                    },
                                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                                      "AppLocalizations.of(context)!.joinGameDialogJoinButton,",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                      stepGranularity: 1,
                                      minFontSize: 1,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),
                          const Text("some eula text"),
                        ]))
                  ],
                ),
              )));
```

The difference with the original code should be only these:

- I removed the container width because on Windows it was really too small to test
- I wrapped the `ElevatedButton` in an `Expanded` following some `auto_size_text` suggestion
- I changed the `minFontSize` to 1 (obviously too low, but useful for testing)
- I put some random texts in the buttons, leaving the second one very long
- I removed the `onPressed` argument just for testing

This is what I got:

- big window [image]
- small window [image]

The minimum font size must be adjusted, but I think that there's no way to have a readable text AND having `maxLines: 1`. You probably must choose one of them, or settle for a very small text.

EDIT:
here's how it looks with `maxLines: 2`: [image]

EDIT 2:
The trick using an empty `Expanded` to keep the button separated and avoiding a full-width second button:

```
[...]
const Expanded(child: Text('')),
Expanded(
   child: ElevatedButton(
   [...]
```

Result, with short text in the second button:

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, using expanded. The problem is, that it now expands the buttons always. Also if there is only short text in it. This is not what I wanted :( I used `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` in `Row` for that reason, to seperate the buttons from each other.

Comment: You can add an "empty" `Expanded` between the two button to keep the second button smaller, maybe even setting different `flex` on them to mange their respective sizes. I edited the answer.

Comment: neat idea, but when doing so, the buttons will not expand anymore in width when there is longer text inside. it just stays the same for me and font gets smaller. see: https://i.imgur.com/rOzMUlF.png

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the answer i have added spacer() for in between space

```
Dialog(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                //width: 100,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        OutlinedButton(
                                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                              side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                              primary: Colors.black54),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                          child: const Text("weerwerewrweee", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                        ),
                                        Spacer(),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 3,
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                                  primary: Colors.white),
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                // if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                                //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                //   widget.onFinished(nameController.text.trim());
                                                // }
                                              },
                                              child: const Text(
                                                "TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest",
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,

                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),
                                    const Text("some eula text"),
                                  ]))
                            ],
                          ),
                        )))
```

Comment: Problem is, this only works again with the `flex`-value, which takes all responsiveness from the concept.

Answer (score 0):

SizedBox is used for this condition only.
You can use sizedbox to size any of the Widget.
In your case,
Try with this code -

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      color: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              child: OutlinedButton(
                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                    side: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2,
                                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                    primary: Colors.black54),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: Text("Raushan is flutter developer",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    primary: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () async {},
                                child: Text("Raushan is flutter developer",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),
                        Text("some eula text"),
                      ]))
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

I think this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**No need of using any dependency**

---

Use custom class **AdaptableText** in your project.

### adaptable_text.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class AdaptableText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final double minimumFontScale;
  final TextOverflow textOverflow;
  const AdaptableText(this.text,
      {this.style,
        this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
        this.textDirection = TextDirection.ltr,
        this.minimumFontScale = 0.5,
        this.textOverflow = TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TextPainter _painter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: this.text, style: this.style),
        textAlign: this.textAlign,
        textScaleFactor: 1,
        maxLines: 100,
        textDirection: this.textDirection);

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        _painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
        double textScaleFactor = 1;

        if (_painter.height > constraints.maxHeight) { //
          print('${_painter.size}');
          _painter.textScaleFactor  = minimumFontScale;
          _painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
          print('${_painter.size}');

          if (_painter.height > constraints.maxHeight) { //
            //even minimum does not fit render it with minimum size
            print("Using minimum set font");
            textScaleFactor = minimumFontScale;
          } else if (minimumFontScale < 1) {
            //binary search for valid Scale factor
            int h = 100;
            int l =   (minimumFontScale * 100).toInt();
            while (h > l) {
              int mid = (l + (h - l) / 2).toInt();
              double newScale = mid.toDouble()/100.0;
              _painter.textScaleFactor  = newScale;
              _painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);

              if (_painter.height > constraints.maxHeight) { //
                h = mid - 1;
              } else {
                l = mid + 1;
              }
              if  (h <= l) {
                print('${_painter.size}');
                textScaleFactor = newScale - 0.01;
                _painter.textScaleFactor  = newScale;
                _painter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
                break;
              }


            }
          }
        }

        return Text(
          this.text,
          style: this.style,
          textAlign: this.textAlign,
          textDirection: this.textDirection,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          maxLines: 100,
          overflow: textOverflow,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

Now use this class

```
 Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: AdaptableText(mediumSizeText, style: const TextStyle()),
      ),
```

---

Here i am also showing the difference between normal text, text inside size box and adaptive text

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('ExpandableText'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      const Text('Normal Text'),
      Text(mediumSizeText),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      const Text('Container(250*20) Normal Text:'),
      Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text(
          mediumSizeText,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      const Text('Container(250*20) => sizebox => Text:'),
      Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          child: Text(
            mediumSizeText,
            maxLines: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Text('Container(250*20) => AdaptableText => Text:'),
      Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: AdaptableText(mediumSizeText, style: const TextStyle()),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

**Here is the result:**

[image]